# Teradata - Numeric overflow occurred during computation

Tags: sql, casting, teradata

I am having an issue with a calculation in one of my Teradata queries.  I am multiplying two numbers by each other but i am getting a "Numeric overflow occurred during computation." error when running the query.  I ran a type on both fields and they are DECIMAL(18,15) and DECIMAL(18,9).  I tried casting them both to DECIMAL(18,18) when i do the division but its still throwing errors.  Here is the calculation. UNITS is the 18,15 and PRICE is the 18,9. Can anyone please give me any tips on how to resolve this?

```
cast(UNITS as DECIMAL(18,18))* cast(PRICE as DECIMAL(18,18)) as  NEW_CALC
```

Thanks,

Craig

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use wrong datatypes, a `DECIMAL(18,15)` means 18 digits, 15 of them fractional, so the maximum value is `999.999999999999999`.

And when you multiply two decimals, the number of fractional digits adds up, `NEW_CALC` results in 38 fractional digits. Do a `TYPE(cast(UNITS as DECIMAL(18,18))* cast(PRICE as DECIMAL(18,18)))`.

This will work:

```
cast(UNITS as DECIMAL(38,15))* PRICE
```

But you better change the column's datatype to something like (18,2) or (18,4), I don't think anyone uses more than 4 digits for prices.

Comment: Yep, i used the second option you gave.  That works.  I just didn't understand what i was doing :/  Thanks for the help!